Can I install a previously used meter box with knockout plugs?
I'm trying to set up electrical service for my barn, on a budget.
It was recommended to me to set up a power pole outside of the barn and then run the service to the electrical panel inside.
I'm being told you can't use a box that has the holes already punched out. I don't understand this because you have to punch out the holes to run the wires anyway.
I'm in Davidson county North Carolina

Davidson county where?

Would this be the inside pael, or the box on the pole outside? If the latter, it needs to be raintight and all holes should normally be located where leaks won't means dripping water on live parts. Sometimes a top-mounted sealed "hub" fitting is OK.

This would be the box on the pole outside. On the used box, the punch out on the bottom has been removed. This would be where the wires go out, right?

Who is your electric utility?

DO NOT SCRIMP ON THE LOAD CENTER / PANEL.  We see so many people do this, and later they find themselves in a real jam because they're plumb out of circuit breaker spaces.  And this problem costs them far more than a new 30-space panel would have cost them.  Get it from Habitat for Humanity store if you must, but get a BIG panel.
Other than that, they make knockout seals.  They even make waterproof ones.
For the top of meters, the manufacturer also makes hub closure plates, or even small-diameter hub covers that you can just put a pipe plug into.
Note that for an electric service, like the utility itself will be hooking wires into this meter --- it's no longer legal to use plain old meter pans and then have the main breaker indoors.  You must have an outside main breaker near the meter.   You can either use a brand new "meter-main", a standalone main breaker, or use an outdoor NEMA rated panel.
That outside main/disconnect requirement is a NEC 2020 thing, that's why meter pans without it are so cheap now LOL.

I suspect the OP will need an outside main breaker, but due to the ag building stuff, not the dwelling emergency disco stuff

The used box is a large power pole box. There should be plenty of room.  I just don't understand why it wouldn't pass 1st inspection.  Thanks for letting me know about the knockout seals! I think that will solve my problem.
